# Data persistence not possible when running scheduled task

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, backend, spring-scheduled

**General Idea:**
My task is about saving / updating data on the DB on scheduled interval.
For the interaction with the DB I'm using a JPA repository.

**Code Snippets:**

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class Executer {

   @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository;

   @Transactional
   public void testSaving() {
      final User user = new User();
      user.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
      user.setUserId("ABCD123S");
      user.setName("TEST_FROM_SCHEDULER");

      final var savedU = userRepository.save(user);
      log.info("SAVED::USER::OBJ> {}", savedU);
      log.info("SAVED::USER::GET:DN> {}",
      userRepository.findByUserId("ABCD123S").get().getDisplayName());
  }
}

@Slf4j
@Service
public class Scheduler {
  @Autowired private Executer executer;

  @Scheduled(cron = "${cron-job-interval}")
  public void test() {
      executer.testSaving();
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "scheduler.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class SchedulerConfig {}
```

**Logs:**

```
"SAVED::USER::OBJ> com.demo.app.dao.User@d1a2bbd1","process.thread.name":"scheduling-1"
"SAVED::USER::GET:DN> TEST_FROM_SCHEDULER","process.thread.name":"scheduling-1"
```

**The Problem:**
As seen in the Logs, the execution is done successfully. However, when I check the DB, none of the entries were persisted. The entity manager and the scheduler are running in different threads, might this be the problem?

Comment: Everything looks fine. Can you enable SQL logging and check if the statements are executed

Comment: My Latest finding is: @Scheduler is not committing the Transaction to the DB.  Tried all possible ways I know.